# Including code-block in a another file

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible for a code-block in one org file to include a noweb reference to a code-block in another org file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the case of dereferencing noweb references for export the include feature of Org does the trick.

Example (see the Org mode info pages for the fullest-disk code):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle yes :noweb yes :shebang #!/bin/sh
<<fullest-disk>>
#+END_SRC
#+INCLUDE: "path to the org file defining fullest-disk"
```

AFAICS the include feature does not work for tangling.

For getting a tangle one could concatenate the files.  E.g.

`cat my-code-blocks-lib.org main.org > tangle-me.org`

and then tangle file `tangle-me.org`.

And also note the **library of babel** aka **lob**.  You can ingest a file into the lob which means that its source code blocks are available in every Org file.

E.g. have a file chilllib.org:

```
#+NAME: chill
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
echo chill...
#+END_SRC
```

Then ingest

`M-x org-babel-lob-ingest chilllib.org`

and use e.g. the following block in some Org file for execution or tangling

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :tangle yes :noweb yes :shebang #!/bin/sh
<<chill>>
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Does `#+include` work for evaluating blocks containing noweb references to included files? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: `org-babel-lob-ingest` doesn't work `:noweb-ref ...` header argument?